# is there a name for a dimension which has data insert/append

Tags: oracle, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

Is there a name for a dimension in the context of dimensional data warehousing 
if the data in the dimension is always insert/append. how do I classify this dimension as? is it a type1, type2, hybrid etc?

Thanks for looking into the question

Comment: I think this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension) should provide a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

SCD refers to changes occurred in the entities of a dimension.
*Insert/append* table does not directly refer in any way to the above.
You can use *insert/append* way to capture changes in a normalized model by timestamping any change. This normalization may not be ideal if you are talking about data mart - due to performance of each query. But it is good as history table from which fast ETL tool can produce SCD2 data mart having effective date start-end fields and a current flag. So the queries can easily and fast utilize SQL's `BETWEEN`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is SCD0.

A good example of an SCD0 dimension would be a calendar. We never need to modify a row, the calendar never changes, we only append new rows to the dimension.